# Pass properties to log4j before it loads

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Is there a way to pass data or setting to log4j before it loads and then use that property within the config file.

I was assuming there is a system properties I could use:

log4j.appender.R.File=/usr/local/pfs/logs/${ws.host}/log4j.log

Where ws.host is the property I want to use.

But how can I set that value?

Also, I am in a web environment.  How can I know at what point to set the property setting before log4j loads.

Comment: Are you talking about setting it through code or through a command line argument?

Comment: I am in a web environment.  I was hoping I could set the log4j setting in code System.properties.put()?  and then in my log4j file, set the configuration.

Answer (score 4):

The default log4j PropertiesConfigurator supports variable substitution.

- http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html

So, you could pass system properties like this `"-DmyProject.logFile="/temp/test.log"` to your Java startup, and then in the properties files have `"log4j.appender.R.File=${myProject.logFile}"`.

If working from a web environment, you might want to check out Spring's [Log4jConfigListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jConfigListener.html). It uses a listener (Servlet API 2.4+) to initialization log4j ahead of other components.  Even if not using Spring, you should be able to use the source as an example to easily create your own listener.

Comment: It can help here to use a different log4j config file name than log4j.properties, and then call the PropertyConfigurator explicit after setting log4j.configuration in your code. This gives you better control over the log4j configuration sequence. It requires that you do not use any logger before - static final variables of type Logger are also problematic here...